# XAML bind to static method with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a static class like the following:

```
public static class Lang
{
   public static string GetString(string name)
   {
      //CODE
   }
}
```

Now i want to access this static function within xaml as a binding.
Is there such a way for example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path="{x:static lang:Lang.GetString, Parameters={parameter1}}"/>
```

Or is it necessary to create a ObjectDataProvider for each possible parameter?

Hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not create a converter, or format the string e.g. Content="{Binding Path=MyValue, StringFormat=You searched for {0}}"/> ?

Comment: the string.Format was just a example output. Will clearify the question.

Answer (score 24):

I get this need too. I "solved" using a converter (like suggested [here](http://goo.gl/Gd7bJH)).

First, create a converter which return the translated string:

```
public class LanguageConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (parameter == null)
      return string.Empty;

    if (parameter is string)
      return Resources.ResourceManager.GetString((string)parameter);
    else
      return string.Empty;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

then use it into XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:LanguageConverter x:Key="LangConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LangConverter}, 
                         ConverterParameter=ResourceKey}"/>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 7):

The right way would be to go the objectdataprovider route. Although if you are just binding to text rather than use a label, I would use a textblock.

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="yourStaticData"
                ObjectType="{x:Type lang:Lang}"
                MethodName="GetString" >
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters> 
                     <s:String>Parameter1</s:String> 
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<TextBlock Text={Binding Source={StaticResource yourStaticData}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach would mean i have to create a own ObjectDataProvider for every different parameter. Or is it possible to change the ObjectDataProvider parameter through the binding statement?

For example:
<TextBlock Text={Binding Source={StaticResource yourStaticData[parameter1]}}/>

Comment: Looking at the msdn linking the only way my suggestion would work is if the MethodParameters was bound to something that specified the value. So I guess my answer might not be what you are looking for. http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/02/23/bind-objectdataprovider-method-parameters-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help!